# Boxplot hierarchical clustering with Tukey multiple comparison of means

Tags: r, boxplot

I need to test whether the content of few boxplots are significantly different and associate a letter code to each group.

For example like this

Is there any function of package able to do that ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two different functions for Tukey post-hoc comparisons you can run along with an ANOVA.

Let's say your comparison is:

```
f <- as.formula("Petal.Length ~ Species")

boxplot(f, iris) # here's your boxplot

fit <- lm(f, iris)

anova(fit) # the effect of Species is significant

av <- aov(f, iris)
```

(Instead of `Species`, you would use the cluster ID obtained from `hclust()`, and instead of `Petal.Length` you would use FQI or whatever you want on the y axis.)

In base R, you can do:

```
post_hoc <- TukeyHSD(x=av, conf.level=0.95)
print(post_hoc)
plot(post_hoc)
```

and look for the overlapping groups that way (in this example they don't overlap).

There is also another implementation that gives you the group codes you are looking for, but I am less familiar with it.

```
library("agricolae")
HSD.test(av, "iris$Petal.Length", console=TRUE)
```

I don't think I got the syntax quite right, as it's not returning the results, but it should help you get started.  I think you'll find this article on [Anova and Tukey's Test on R](http://www.r-bloggers.com/anova-and-tukeys-test-on-r/) helpful -- a similar example with more explanation.

As for how to annotate the boxplots directly, I imagine this could be done by passing the post-hoc grouping vector into `ggplot2::geom_text` alongside a `geom_boxplot`, but I'm not sure it can be done in base `boxplot()`.